# argparse .ArgumentParser raise ArgumentError

Tags: python, argparse

```
conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1510, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--height: conflicting option string: -h
```

The above is the error message,
here is my code,
I don't see the error:

# 1) Parse the arguments

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description for my parser")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--velocity", action="store", required=True, help="The velocity of the object is required")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--angle", action="store", type=float, required=True, help="The angle of the object is required")
parser.add_argument("-h", "--height", required=False, default= 1.2, help="The height of the object is not required. Default is set to 1.2 meters" )
```

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong.  Is this possibly a conflict with a built in help option?  I'd suggest renaming -h/--height temporarily and see if the error goes away. - I would hope you could disable the auto-help option if that's the problem.

Comment: A `-h` argument is automatically created, it means 'help'.  Your '-h' conflicts with that.

Answer (score 10):

Option "-h" is by default predefined as a "help" option, which prints the description and the list of arguments. Your custom "-h --height" conflicts with this, thus causing an error.

It wouldn't be nice to overwrite the default "-h --help" option, because many users expect "-h" option to print help message. (So if I were you I would find another way to name the option.) But you can ignore it if you really need to by using [`add_help` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help) with the constructor. Like this:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description for my parser", add_help=False)
```

If you want to keep "--help" option, you have to add another line of `parser.add_argument("--help", action="help")`. (Thanks to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner))

Comment: Note that adding back explicit support for a help option can be as simple as `parser.add_argument("--help", action='help')`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you are using a param name who is conflicting with other. Particularly in this case the -h option. The lib argparse always include the -h option to print the script help, so for the height, you must use a different param than -h, for example -ht.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description for my parser")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--velocity", action="store", required=True, help="The velocity of the object is required")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--angle", action="store", type=float, required=True, help="The angle of the object is required")
parser.add_argument("-ht", "--height", required=False, default= 1.2, help="The height of the object is not required. Default is set to 1.2 meters" )
```